# How to overplot in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

I have a function `f(n,x)=n(x+x**2)` with `0<=x<=1` and `n=0,1,..,9.` And using 100 points for x (delx=1/100) would like to over-plot the graph on f(x) for each value of n.
These are my codes

```
import matplot.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(n,x):
    return n(x+x**2)

x = np.arange(0,1,0.01)
n = 0
while n<10:
    n=n+1
    plt.plot(x,f(n,x))
    plt.show()
```

The result is the straight line, yet i guess it should be multiple lines for `n=0,1,..,9`

Answer (score 1):

You have to move `plt.show()` out of the loop, what you're doing right now is creating a separate figure for each iteration.
Here's a working version of what you're trying to achieve:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(n, x):
    return n*(x+x**2)

x = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
n = 0
while n < 10:
    n = n+1
    plt.plot(x, f(n, x))
plt.show()
```